# Keep my list/dictionary as globally accessible

Tags: c#, list, class, object, dictionary

Ok... I'm trying to understand this whole object oriented programming but I keep ending up in a dead end.  ;)

I'm trying to store or rather will store a great deal of data with using classes as I should. I want to store planetary data by using a class with several properties, I will then save these into a list.

My problem is that I don't know how to make this list globally accessible, it is only accessible in the instance where it is created.

Some sample code from my test environment below.

OrbitalBodies.cs

```
class OrbitalBodies
{
    public int BodyID { get; set; }
    public string BodyName { get; set; }
    public int BodySize { get; set; }
    public int BodyX { get; set; }
    public int BodyY { get; set; }   
}
```

From1.cs

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var bodies0 = new OrbitalBodies();
    var orbitalList = new List<OrbitalBodies>();

    bodies0.BodyID = 4;
    bodies0.BodyName = "Earth";
    bodies0.BodySize = 125;
    bodies0.BodyX = -450;
    bodies0.BodyY = 75;

    orbitalList.Add(bodies0);

    bodies0.BodyID = 0;
    bodies0.BodyName = "Sol";
    bodies0.BodySize = 500;
    bodies0.BodyX = 0;
    bodies0.BodyY = 0;

    orbitalList.Add(bodies0);



    //var orbitalDic = new Dictionary<int, OrbitalBodies>();


    MessageBox.Show("Planetary body name: " + Convert.ToString(orbitalList.Count()));
}
```

I have spent a couple of hours looking up my problem here and other places but I don't know how I can access the information I put into the list other than in that single instance. My real application will have tens of thousands of orbital bodies and many other data that must be accessible throughout many forms and perhaps even other classes.

Some help would be appreciated, what is the best solution? Do it completely differently?!?

Comment: You probably don't *want* it to be global, from an application design perspective.  While it seems easier at first that trying to determine what it's proper scope is and ensuring it is scoped at that level, this programming methodology turns your whole application into a bunch of spaghetti code that becomes really hard to work with, understand, and maintain over time.  Also note that you'll need to deal with thread safety issues if you expose this information globally; and those can be a real pain.

Comment: @Servy its not entirely true. Many things, mostly in game development, uses static data to store game (world) or other things, that do not change during run or needed to be accesible from everywhere and everytime.

Comment: @MartinPerry I wasn't say you shouldn't ever make anything globally accessible, I was simply saying that, in this context, it doesn't seem to be appropriate given what he's doing, and that it's rare to be in a situation where it's appropriate.  If that wasn't clear I apologize.

Comment: @Martin Perry: No excuse for making it a global variable. Dependency injection is the way forward dude.

Comment: Well, this is the beginning of a type of game. A game that will handle quite allot of data. Not the common mainstream shooter sort of...;) I will need quite alot of data to be accessible all the time, reading from a database will only be viable during save and load. More or less...

Answer (score 3):

You don't want static members or singletons (both of which cause more problems than they solve), you need [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Outside of your form create the List, pass it into the forms constructor. Everywhere you need to use the list, pass the instance you have from the form.

This way there is only one list, everywhere that needs the list is passed *a* list (that just happens to be the same list).

If in time you realize you actually need to model two different systems, you just create two different lists, and pass them to two different forms, everything keeps working and you don't need to go back through your code removing references to static members.

Honestly, this is completely doable without going to the dark side and perpetuating the evil that is static/global variables.

NB [Why static variables are considered evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil)

Comment: As much as I agree with DI being a good solution here, that's not to say that a static variable *can't* do the job - like I say if it's managed correctly it can work. I have seen static variables used in application design in the past and used well.

Comment: Yeah, it's like saying you don't need a hammer to get a nail into some wood, you can use a glass bottle instead . . . if you manage it correctly. The correct tool for the job is still a hammer.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier it's more like saying there is more than one type of hammer - both solutions do job.

Comment: @james: We may agree to differ mate, I don't see global/static variables as a type of hammer.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier well I personally wouldn't class DI as a hammer either but it was the analogy you used haha fair enough, point being if global/static variables weren't to be used, they wouldn't exist and I think (in this particular instance) it would do the job. Multi-threaded environment however...probably not.

Comment: Goto's exist, and it's well established that they should never _(where never -> 0)_ be used e.g. [GOTO still considered harmful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful) and [screw good practice, how bad could it be](http://xkcd.com/292/). I'm at the point where I'd happily put _global variables_ in the same rocket with _goto_ and shoot them both into the sun.

Comment: You are condemning the tool rather than the workman here though, it's not that GOTOs/global variables are bad, it's the fact that (more often than not) they are misused. Not that I am saying use this stuff in everyday programming - just merely reiterating they *do* have a purpose can do a job **if used correctly**.

Comment: @James Ouch, looks like [you have him on the ropes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0e2kaQqxmQ0)

Comment: I'll happily condemn both the tool and the work man :) lets agree to disagree mate.

Answer (score 1):

Use design pattern [Singleton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx).

```
public class Globals 
{
   private List<OrbitalBodies>() orbiralList;
   private static Globals instance;

   private Globals()
   {
      this.orbiralList = new List<OrbitalBodies>();
      this.instance = NULL;
   }

   public static List<OrbitalBodies>() GetOrbitalBodies()
   { 
      if (instance == null) instance = new Globals();

      return instance.orbitaList;
   }

}
```

Then everywhere in your code, when you will need `orbitalList` call

```
Globals.GetOrbitalBodies().<do whatever with your list>
```

Try not to use static classes, because they are mess in term of OO design.

Comment: No, [singletons are evil](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons)

Comment: Better than static classes. And for many things, they are good solution. Not in this case though, but for beginner, if he wants "fast" to see some result, they are enough.

Comment: @MartinPerry It's not really any different than a static class at all, at least as it is.  About the only real difference is that a singleton can implement an interface and leverage polymorphism, but you aren't doing that, so it's not really any better off.

Comment: No, not better, static classes are just as evil, and I couldn't disagree more mate, there is a vanishingly small set of problems for which a global variable is a "good solution". In time it will bite you in the ass. Better to take the pain up front and do it right the first time.

Comment: @Servy I think that in memory static class is somewhere else. Singleton class is stored as any other class, only its instance is placed elsewhere.

Comment: @MartinPerry And why does it matter that there is a static reference to an object with a reference to a list instead of just a static reference to a List?  What difference (in this context) does it make?

Comment: @MartinPerry: Where it's stored doesn't matter, you're still accessing it through a single static globally available location. It's just as bad mate, sorry.

Comment: OK :) Dependency Injection looks like cleaner solution, though I never used them

Comment: @MartinPerry I'm sure you have.  You may not have called it that, but you have.

Comment: Exactly what do you all propose to do when most of those values will be used continuously through the game. Planetary bodies will change perhaps every five to thirty seconds, depending on which pace the player choose to act on?

Answer (score 0):

Make `OrbitalList` a property:

```
public List<OrbitalBodies> OrbitalList {get;set;}

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var bodies0 = new OrbitalBodies();

    bodies0.BodyID = 4;
    bodies0.BodyName = "Earth";
    bodies0.BodySize = 125;
    bodies0.BodyX = -450;
    bodies0.BodyY = 75;

    OrbitalList.Add(bodies0);
    //...
}

//Then you can do:
doSomething(myForm.OrbitalList[0]);
```

Comment: It just tell me that ''public static List<OrbitalBodies> OrbitalBodyList { get; set; }'' inconsistent accessibility... is less accessible than property.

Comment: Your `Form` must be `public` (or `OrbitalList` `internal`)

Comment: As far as I can tell the form is a 'public partial class'

Comment: Why is OrbitalBodyList static?!

Comment: Ok, I solved it... the class being called also had to be a public class and not a default class.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to access your list within the "Form1" class, just declare it as a private member out of a function:

```
private List<OrbitalBodies> _orbitalList;
```

and then instanciate it into your "button1_Click" method.

If you want to access your list in all your classes, I suggest you make it static :

```
public class NewClass
{

   public static List<OrbitalBodies> OrbitalList {get; set;};

}
```

and you call it like this

```
NewClass.OrbitalList;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: No, [static variables are evil](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil)

Comment: Ok, I learned something today. But you didn't have to downvote my answer, as I was trying to help.

Comment: Sorry bud but I didn't downvote your answer. I wouldn't downvote answers on a question where I've also provided an answer.

Comment: Sadly the information must be accessible through many forms.  :(

Comment: @orel I find binary's crusade against static variables is weird. Thanks orel, this helps. Seeing as how static variables work to accomplish a goal, I see nothing wrong with using them. If there isn't a problem doing something, then doing it isn't wrong. Silly programmers. I will never understand their syntax arguments.